# In iOS, should we save Image as Binary Data or use a library?

Tags: ios, image, core-data

I'm writing an app to consume REST Api which provide `JSON` response. I'm using `CoreData` to store object from `JSON` to support offline feature. Object has some image attributes (Which is image url from JSON response).

My question is should I store image attributes as `Data` (Using binary data) to `CoreData` (can check use external storage from `CoreDataXCModel`) or should I need to only store the image path (As String) and use some library such as `Kingfisher`, `AlamofireImage`, `SDWebImage` to load image from image url stored in Coredata? which one is better design?

1 more thing is for how we handle big image? Can we generate 1 thumbnail which is specific size and 1 full image size.

Comment: - Better way is to store url only in database. and load them view lazy loading. it will reduce a lot memory consuming tasks.

- Better ask to web team to generate both image at their side and send url to mobile team.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Can explain view lazy loading? and also generate both image means 2 url for thumbnail and original size?

Comment: #SDWebImage will do that for you.

Comment: - Can we generate 1 thumbnail which is specific size and 1 full image size: for this question i suggest to make different url from web side for different size of images.

Comment: Thanks, Will look through lazy loading. Which library should be recommended? Kingfisher, AlamofireImage, SDWebImage?

Comment: SDWebImage is giving better performance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest you to store URL in database and use some framework like SDWebImage to load. These frameworks have caching mechanism so that once an image is loaded it gets cached.

You could preferably get a thumbnail image as a link in the JSON response too.

Comment: Thanks. If we only have 1 url for big image from JSON response. What should we do? should we create own thumbnail version?

Comment: It is always better to get the thumbnail from the web service as we are shooting up the processing power of the app if we try to create the thumbnail. Yes if there is no other option you may create a thumbnail and store it.

Answer (score 1):

Save the urlString, I think, in most cases the urlStrting is a better solution, because in the era of 3 g / 4 g mobile phone App has greater amounts of image data, the local store they are a very difficult thing, unless you have a 1024 TB of the iPhone.

And you should provide an interface, like long press to push an view(Or anything) to tell user they can save the image to local.

Don't forget load local image at first and provide an interface tell user they can remove the local data.